# html5 forms need php validation before inserting in to mysql?

Tags: html, forms

My sign up form works on HTML5 inputs (email,password,username..) also using patterns . Do i need to check the inputs with php to before inserting them in to mysql?

Comment: Yes, you do need to do validation and sanitation of all user inputs on server-side, even if you do it on client side. You have no guarantee where the data came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

Remember that *anyone* can send raw HTTP requests and fill in the fields with any data they like. Never trust user input; always check it server-side.